# How to configure a domain name for use within the LAN only

Tags: windows-server-2003, internal-dns

I wish to create a domain name for use within the local LAN only. I have Windows Server 2003. Please guide me.

Comment: This question needs more detail including what references were already checked/read

Answer (score 4):

Please read the following:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

and then this

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814591

If you read with intent to understand, this should pretty much take care of you.

Comment: Yes, but i found Active Directory and i downloaded it. but i can't use this. plz help me...

Comment: The Technet article SpacemanSpiff linked to has all the detail you require. You do not need Active Directory in order to run the DNS service.

Comment: I'm sorry, Nyi Nyi Naing, but DNS is one of those systems that needs a bit of design and thought before you can use it. We can't tell you "just push this button, and type *whatever* in" because the system doesn't work that way. If you have a broad grasp of what it is you're trying to do we can help with some specific questions but its impossible to go much beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

To create a DNS domain, you need to first install the Microsoft DNS service component of Windows Server.  You can find this component under the ***control panel/add remove programs applet*** under the ***install Windows components*** section.

Once DNS is installed, under administrative tools you can find an MMC snap-in to manage it.  Once you've opened the management tool, create a new ***Forward Lookup Zone***.  You can do this by right-clicking on the ***Forward Lookup Zone*** folder.  When you name the forward lookup zone, you should take care to ***not*** use a domain name found on the Internet already.  If you do, lookups to that domain will fail unless you mirror its records perfectly or perform a zone transfer (which will likely require some type of authentication).  I usually name internal DNS zones at home using the *.home* or *.internal* top level schemas (*mynet.internal* is one example).

Once you have a zone created you need to populate it with records.  ***A*** records, or ***host records*** are used to create name -> IP lookups for IPv4.  If I created an A record called *computer* in the *mynet.internal* zone with the IP address 192.168.0.2 associated with it and I have a computer with my new DNS server registered as it's method for performing lookups then I will be able to resolve *computer.mynet.internal* to the aforementioned IP address.

Things you should look into after this is working:

**Forwarding** (to use your ISPs DNS server or something like OpenDNS for lookups not in your domain)
Reverse Lookup Zones
Host Record Types

I hope this helps.